# T-SQL Trigger - Delete from Inserted, and Errors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm not seeing any documentation on what happens if you delete from the tables passed to triggers.  Is it documented?

2nd question, I don't see any answers saying how to error out a statement (insert/update/delete) from inside a trigger. Like the proper way, the planned by microsoft way.

Comment: According to microsoft `You cannot directly modify the data in the tables or perform data definition language (DDL) operations on the tables, such as CREATE INDEX.`

Comment: Read the section on triggers for [`Rollback Transaction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#interoperability).